# Can llvm lli excute swift ir

Tags: llvm

I have a function (written in Swift) and I would like to get the LLVM IR for the function PLUS any dependencies so that I can run the resulting LLVM IR in a fully self-contained environment.

As an example, consider the following function:

```
func plus(a: Int, b: Int) ->Int {
    return a + b
}

plus(5, 7)
```

I can pass the `emit-ir` option to `swiftc`, however, the resulting LLVM IR contains external calls and the resulting IR cannot be run using `lli` (the error is shown below).

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__TFSsa6C_ARGVGVSs20UnsafeMutablePointerGS_VSs4Int8__' which could not be resolved!
```

Is there any way of grabbing the IR for these external functions so that I can use `lli` to run the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to teach the `lli` about dependencies of the binary.
Here is how to do so.

Let's say there is a "hello world" program:

```
// main.swift
print("hello")
```

Compile it to LLVM Bitcode and to a normal executable:

```
> swiftc main.swift -o hello
> swiftc -emit-bc main.swift -o hello.bc
```

If you run the `main.bc` via `lli` as is, then you will have a similar error to the one you saw with your program.

To learn about dependencies you can use `otool` on macOS and `ldd` on Linux:

```
> otool -L /path/to/executbale
> ldd /path/to/executbale
```

Here are dependencies for the "hello world" program:

```
> otool -L ./hello
./hello:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1450.15.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
    @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 900.0.74)
    @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 900.0.74)
```

In this case, we need to pass `libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib` and `libswiftCore.dylib` to `lli` sing `-load` option.

On my machine these libraries live in this directory (I used `find` to find them):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx
```

Finally, here is how you can run your program:

```
> lli \
    -load=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftCore.dylib \
    -load=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib \
    hello.bc
```

Also, note the order of arguments: it is important that the bitcode file goes last.

Comment: thanks! I do the same thing and it works! But i add "import Foundation" couldnot

Comment: It told me "Reason: image not found -load request ignored."

Comment: Double check the file path?