# How to load a LLVM function pass on swift?

Tags: swift, llvm

I see the swift source but not found interface to load dylib on compile time.
Anyone knows it？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can llvm lli excute swift ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293032/can-llvm-lli-excute-swift-ir)

Comment: @arnt NO. I found a way. use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES env can inject dylib to swiftc. write some hook code may be can add custom function pass to swift compile time.

Answer (score 0):

check this link I refer this answer when I try to call function I hope it will work for you too ....:)

[Can llvm lli excute swift ir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293032/can-llvm-lli-excute-swift-ir)

Comment: thanks. I want use swiftc support load dylib. like clang -Xclang -load -Xclang xxx.dylib

Comment: ohk if it works then make it right and up vote the post so any other person can also find the right answer ...:)